# Confusion in JTextField () of jython in sikuli

Tags: jython, textfield, sikuli

This is my code :-

```
    from javax.swing import *

    class Example(JFrame):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Example, self).__init__()

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            panel = JPanel()
            panel.setLayout(None)
            self.getContentPane().add(panel)

            panel.setLayout(None)

            area = JTextField('',15)
            panel.add(JLabel("username:", SwingConstants.RIGHT))
            panel.add(area)

            self.setTitle("Quit button")
            self.setSize(600, 400)
            self.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
            self.setVisible(True)

        def onQuit(self, e):
            System.exit(0)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Example()
```

Here I am just trying to make of use JTextField() so that I can get some input from the user.  But after running it, the window was blank, there was no text field on the window. I ran it in sikuli r930 on windows 7.  Could anyone tell me what has gone wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with layout in your code. Try to set some layout instead of "None". Fixed initUI function could look like this:

```
def initUI(self):
    panel = JPanel()
    panel.setLayout(FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,1,150))
    self.getContentPane().add(panel)
    area = JTextField('',15)
    panel.add(JLabel("username:", SwingConstants.RIGHT))
    panel.add(area)
    self.setTitle("Quit button")
    self.setSize(600, 400)
    self.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
    self.setVisible(True)
```

Additional import line is needed in this case:

```
from java.awt import FlowLayout
```

Comment: Yes, it is working, but could you tell me how to set the location of text field. As of now When I execute this code, the text field appear at north-center position.  Moreover I added two buttons to the code, they also appeared on the north-center position.  Is there any way that I can set the location for "FlowLayout"??

Comment: I've updated my answer. Text field now appears in center part of a frame. More about FlowLayout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html . You can use any other layout too.